# How to check if a name has been inputed into a database form notepad

Tags: python, database, notepad

I am currently creating a program where I have to enter data into a database, in this instance notepad. What is the simplest way of doing that. I would need to have a line with their name on it and then there scores. I would then need to be able to add more data to there names later on. 
Thanks in advance!
Let me know if you need more information

Comment: Notepad isn't a database.

Comment: It might not be an actual database, but you can still use it for instance retrieve and enter data into it